# GCC template deduction removes const bug?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I found this snippet compiles and runs with GCC7.3 but not with clang7:

```
const std::vector foo({1, 2, 3, 4});
foo.clear();
```

I expect a compiler error but GCC happily clears the vector.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in version 8: https://godbolt.org/z/Fg7qdW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is GCC bug [83818](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83818); it is fixed with GCC 8.

There is unfortunately not much more information there – the only "fix" appears to be not using class template argument deduction or upgrading the compiler.